# How can I make sure nothing gets autoreleased?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, retain

I need a way to create variables that are accessible for the entire time my custom class is initiated to when I call the release function. I need to retain a NSDate and a NSString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the variable a `retain` message.

Answer (score 1):

Do `[myObject retain]` or `@property(nonatomic, retain) MyClass *myObject;`

Answer (score 1):

Autorelease just fires a -release message at a later time. If you want your variables to stick around, -retain them when they're assigned. Even if they're autoreleased, your retain will increment the retainCount, so they will not be dealloced. Just be sure to -release them in YOUR dealloc.

Comment: I have a string and a date, do I have to have an init method in my own class to send them a retain?

Comment: You can retain them wherever you first initialize, assign or use them.  Before then, your instance objects are all nil pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Give your custom class retain properties for each variable in its header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *myDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;
```

Be sure to create proper setters and getters, or use `@synthesize`, in its implementation file:

```
@synthesize myDate, myString;
```